# Install Eclipse Che 7.0 on a local network server and access from different machines

Tags: minikube, nginx-ingress, eclipse-che

i'm trying to install Eclipse Che 7.0 on a local network server, using the KVM2/Minikube method.

The request is to be able to use Che from another machine on the same network.

My local network is something like 192.168.80.*, the Ingress service maps the Che address on 192.168.39.???.

What's the correct way to map the Che address on the local network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to access minikube instance running in virtual environment from other host in the same network.

The easiest way to do this is to run minikube without vm-driver like following:

```
sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

in this way minikube will start directly on your host machine and not inside of a vm so you won't need to care about forwarding connection to your kubernetes instance.

From now on you can expose your service as nodeport service and access it directly using ip address of your host machine. No proxy/forwarding needed.

Let me know if it was useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently i've moved to another more solid solution, going to a complete Kubernetes deploy architecture.

I've tried using the vm-driver=none way, but it opens some other problems like lack of isolation, so i prefer to change direction.

Comment: @alessio would you mind elaborating sligthly? I have `minikube` running and che `7.21` installed. The addresses are only accessible from the machine it all was installed on. I would like to access it from another machine on the (physical) LAN. Do I need to do some host/port or SSH-magic to get this going? How did you solve it?